# In Html5 we can use "div" inside the "section" tag?

Tags: html

Can one use div inside the section block like below?

```
<section>
 <div>Text</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Yes you can use a `div` inside a `section`.

Comment: we use section when we want separate elements (this same category or similar). First tag inside section should be header (h). Example: one page in newspaper is a section, article is article and on a top this side we have header. More information you can find on this webpage http://html5doctor.com/the-section-element/ If you want have semantic website you can use other element - better.

Comment: Is it fine to use div as a wrapper for section content? I want to style everything inside. Then header would be also inside the div, not as a section first element

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can use a div inside a section.

if you want know much more about div and section difference then you can refer below link.

[explanation of div and section](http://oli.jp/2009/html5-structure1/)

i hop it will helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

yes of course

check [div element can be nested inside the next HTML elements:](http://w3-video.com/Web_Technologies/HTML5/div/html5_div_tag_nested.php)

for any doubts check out the [place in page](http://w3-video.com/Web_Technologies/HTML5/index.php) section of each element; the list of nested elements is provided there

Comment: Those links are now dead